# Segmentation fault on deleting an element after searching it in a heap

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault

The following code deletes an element x from a heap after searching it linearly in the heap

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MaxSize 100001

struct minheap {
    long int a[MaxSize];
    int end;
};

void minHeapify(struct minheap *h, int i) {
    int largest;
    long int temp;
    int l=2*i+1;
    int r=2*i+2;
    largest=i;
    if(l<=(h->end) && (h->a[l])<(h->a[i]))
       largest=l;
    if(r<=(h->end) && (h->a[r])<(h->a[largest]))
       largest=r;
    if(largest!=i) {
       temp=h->a[i];
       h->a[i]=h->a[largest];
       h->a[largest]=temp;
       minHeapify(h,largest);
    }
}


int main() {
    long int x,i=0,temp=0;
    int N;
    int type;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    struct minheap h;
    h.end=-1;

    while(N--) {
        scanf("%d",&type);
        if(type==1) {
              scanf("%ld",&x);
              h.end=h.end+1;
              h.a[h.end]=x;
              i=h.end;
              while(i>0 && h.a[(i-1)/2]>h.a[i]) { //fix minheap on insertion
                  temp = h.a[(i-1)/2];
                  h.a[(i-1)/2]=h.a[i];
                  h.a[i]=temp;
                  i=(i-1)/2;
              }
        }
        else if(type==2) {
              scanf("%ld",&x);

              for(i=0;i<=h.end;i++) {
                  if(x == h.a[i])
                    break;
              }
              h.a[i]=h.a[h.end];
              h.end=h.end-1;
              if(i!=(h.end+1))
              minHeapify(&h,i);
        }

        else if(type==3) {
        printf("%ld\n",h.a[0]);
        }
    }
 return 0;
}
```

But the following test case gives segmentation fault as:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  main () at solution.c:59
59                    if(x == h.a[i])
#0  main () at solution.c:59
```

The entire test case can be found on this link:

https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/15379/input04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1547134261&Signature=D%2B39%2BHr%2F4lRFV%2BetxFwnGWm1iac%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Why is this segmentation fault occurring?

Comment: Something odd about the code you show. `h`, `i`, and `N` are not defined in `main` but that's where you show they are being used. Are you mixing up the body of `main` versus the body of `minHeapify`.

Comment: The code you posted does not compile.  Is this the code you are actually using?

Comment: The OP did say to assume that the variables and functions are already defined

Comment: @Spikatrix - But it is generally a good idea to provide a [mcve].

Comment: "// Consider minHeapify function is already defined here" @ryyker, BUT, when I debug I usually don't trust myself. An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is always a good idea Infinity! :)

Comment: `temp = h.a[(i-1)/2];` loses information.  Post an [MCVE] including sample input "consider all variables are already defined" is insufficient.

Comment: @ryyker I have updated the complete code. I had to abridge it because it said "your question is mostly code", as the code was too long. Sorry I am new here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the error message,

```
> Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
> #0  main () at solution.c:59 59                    if(x == h.a[i])
> #0  main () at solution.c:59
```

...the value `i` in the expression: `if(x == h.a[i])` is probably out of bounds. This leads to *[undefined behavior](https://www.i-programmer.info/news/184-cc/11862-c-undefined-behavior-depressing-and-terrifying.html)*, which in some cases might seem to work, other might lead to a *segmentation fault*.

Look at this line for a possible the solution:

```
for(i=0;i<=h.a[h.end];i++)
```

What is the value of `a.end` at the time this expression is called?

There is also a potential for problems here:

```
while(i>0 && h.a[(i-1)/2]>h.a[i])
```

Where the expression: `(i-1)/2` is integer division, and will skip values.

Comment: It could -i think- be corrected with `for(i=0;i<h.end;i++) {` instead of `for(i=0;i<=h.a[h.end];i++) {` on previous line.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems in your code to delete an item:

```
          for(i=0;i<=h.end;i++) {
              if(x == h.a[i])
                break;
          }
          h.a[i]=h.a[h.end];
          h.end=h.end-1;
          if(i!=(h.end+1))
          minHeapify(&h,i);
```

First, if an item with the value you entered is not found, you're going to have trouble because `i > h.end`. You'll end up either indexing off the end of the array, or deleting the last item.

More importantly, you're not handling the case where the item you replace it with is smaller than the parent. For example, consider this heap:

```
        1
    6       2
  7   8   3
```

If you delete the node with value 7, the value 3 replaces it:

```
        1
    6       2
  3   8
```

That's not a valid heap. You have to move the 3 up in the heap to create:

```
        1
    3       2
  6   8
```

The key here is that if the item you're replacing is in a different subtree than the last item in the heap, it's possible that the replacement node will be smaller than the parent of the replaced node.

So your code has to do this:

```
h.a[i] = h.a[h.end];
h.end = h.end-1;
// here you have to:
// if (h.a[i] < parentOf(h.a[i]))
//    move it up the heap
// else
//    minHeapify(&h, i);
```